# SEF urls htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Currently my url structure is like:

```
http://mysite/index.php?page=main
http://mysite/index.php?page=bowling
http://mysite/index.php?page=inn
```

How to optimize this structure by leaving just (main,bowling,inn respectively) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these rules to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?page=([^&]+)&id=([0-9]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [L,R]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?page=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

make sure mod_rewrite is turned on.

Comment: works fine, but i have also this kind of url index.php?page=sauna&id=8   on my site, and they dont want to work using your recomendations  Any thoughts?

Comment: and could you explain what this  code stands for RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]  ?

Comment: @SergeyBodrov the first rule looks for requests that look like `/index.php?page=XXX` and redirects the browser to `/XXX` and the second rule looks for requests like `/XXX` and internally rewrites back to `/index.php?page=XXX`. If you want to also have it deal with `id=`, that's a completely separate problem

Comment: thank you a lot for help, could you give any recomendation how to tackle the id problem as well? would appreciate it

Comment: @SergeyBodrov you just need to add another set that does exactly the same thing, except it matches against the ID part